# How to edit wordpress plugin .php file

Tags: php, html, wordpress, frontend

I installed the Front-End Publishing plugin on my website, and it displays this menu: 
[FEP menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oa9wz.png)

- I want to remove the 'tags' and 'choose featured image' option from the menu.
- Since I want users to upload *media only* for the post content, I would also like to prevent users from typing words in the content box.

This is the plugin's submission-form.php What code do I have to edit to achive this? (I tried to put all the code in code format but part of the code refused to be put in the code sample box)

```
<?php
$post       = false;
$post_id    = -1;
$featured_img_html = '';
if( isset($_GET['fep_id']) && isset($_GET['fep_action']) && $_GET['fep_action'] == 'edit' ){
    $post_id            = $_GET['fep_id'];
    $p                  = get_post($post_id, 'ARRAY_A');
    if($p['post_author'] != $current_user->ID) return 'You don\'t have permission to edit this post';
    $category           = get_the_category($post_id);
    $tags               = wp_get_post_tags( $post_id, array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );
    $featured_img       = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );
    $featured_img_html  = (!empty($featured_img))?wp_get_attachment_image( $featured_img, array(200,200) ):'';
    $post               = array(
                            'title'             => $p['post_title'],
                            'content'           => $p['post_content'],
                            'about_the_author'  => get_post_meta($post_id, 'about_the_author', true)
                        );
    if(isset($category[0]) && is_array($category))
        $post['category']   = $category[0]->cat_ID;
    if(isset($tags) && is_array($tags))
        $post['tags']       = implode(', ', $tags);
}
?>
```

This form needs JavaScript to function properly. Please turn on JavaScript and try again!

```
<div id="fep-new-post">
<div id="fep-message" class="warning"></div>
<form id="fep-submission-form">
    <label for="fep-post-title">Title</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="post_title" id="fep-post-title" value="<?php echo ($post) ? $post['title']:''; ?>"><br/>
    <label for="fep-post-content">Content</label><br/>
    <?php
        $enable_media = (isset($fep_roles['enable_media']) && $fep_roles['enable_media'])?current_user_can($fep_roles['enable_media']):1;
        wp_editor( $post['content'], 'fep-post-content', $settings = array('textarea_name'=>'post_content', 'textarea_rows'=> 7, 'media_buttons'=>$enable_media) );
        wp_nonce_field('fepnonce_action','fepnonce');
    ?>
    <?php if(!$fep_misc['disable_author_bio']): ?>
        <label for="fep-about">Author Bio</label><br/>
        <textarea name="about_the_author" id="fep-about" rows="5"><?php echo ($post) ? $post['about_the_author']:''; ?></textarea><br/>
    <?php else: ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="about_the_author" id="fep-about" value="-1">
    <?php endif; ?>
    <label for="fep-category">Category</label><br/>
    <?php wp_dropdown_categories(array('id'=>'fep-category', 'hide_empty' => 0, 'name' => 'post_category', 'orderby' => 'name', 'selected' => $post['category'], 'hierarchical' => true, 'show_option_none' => __('None'))); ?><br/>
    <label for="fep-tags">Tags</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="post_tags" id="fep-tags" value="<?php echo ($post) ? $post['tags']:''; ?>"><br/>
    <div id="fep-featured-image">
        <div id="fep-featured-image-container"><?php echo $featured_img_html; ?></div>
        <a id="fep-featured-image-link" href="#">Choose Featured Image</a>
        <input type="hidden" id="fep-featured-image-id" value="<?php echo (!empty($featured_img))?$featured_img:'-1'; ?>"/>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="fep-post-id" value="<?php echo $post_id ?>">
    <button type="button" id="fep-submit-post" class="active-btn">Submit</button><img class="fep-loading-img" src="<?php echo plugins_url( 'static/img/ajax-loading.gif', dirname(__FILE__) ); ?>"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Question # 1:**

Add a class to these elements (I have called the class `removal`)

```
<label for="fep-tags" class="removal">Tags</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="post_tags" class="removal" id="fep-tags" value="<?php echo ($post) ? $post['tags']:''; ?>"><br/>
<div class="removal" id="fep-featured-image">
    <div id="fep-featured-image-container"><?php echo $featured_img_html; ?></div>
    <a id="fep-featured-image-link" href="#">Choose Featured Image</a>
    <input type="hidden" id="fep-featured-image-id" value="<?php echo (!empty($featured_img))?$featured_img:'-1'; ?>"/>
</div>
```

Add custom CSS to your theme:

```
.removal{
  display:none !important;
}
```

**For Question # 2:**

You can do two things. You can completely remove the user's ability to type text in by removing the textarea altogether in CSS:

```
#fep-about{
  display:none !important;
}
```

If for any reason you actually need the text box (not sure why). I would add custom Javascript to detect if the user has entered a key or copy and pasted any text. Considering the ID of the textarea element is `fep-about`:

```
var ele = document.getElementById('fep-about')

ele.addEventListener('keyup',function(){
  this.value = "";
  alert("Only direct media uploads are allowed!");
});

ele.addEventListener('onchange',function(){
  this.value = "";
  alert("Only direct media uploads are allowed!");
});
```

Here is the JSFiddle for this: https://jsfiddle.net/a3zsdo88/1/

**Compatibility Issues**

If there are some sort of issues in CSS classes overriding the above ones, just add the display statements inline with the elements:

```
<div id="fep-featured-image" style="display:none !important;">
    <div id="fep-featured-image-container"><?php echo $featured_img_html; ?>  </div>
    <a id="fep-featured-image-link" href="#">Choose Featured Image</a>
    <input type="hidden" id="fep-featured-image-id" value="<?php echo (!empty($featured_img))?$featured_img:'-1'; ?>"/>
</div>
```

See how I added the display statement to the parent element. Do that for the elements you do not want shown.

If you don't have a way to customize your Javascript easily, then add a `<script></script>` block directly in your HTML in your form file.

```
<script>

   var ele = document.getElementById('fep-about')

   ele.addEventListener('keyup',function(){
     this.value = "";
     alert("Only direct media uploads are allowed!");
   });

   ele.addEventListener('onchange',function(){
     this.value = "";
     alert("Only direct media uploads are allowed!");
   });

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, but I seem to be doing something wrong here. I added code 1 to the bottom of FEP plugin submission form.php. I added code 2,3 and 4 to the CSS stylesheet editor. But nothing has changed on my fep submission form. I have also tried deactivating and reactivating the plugin. I can give you access to the backend on my site if needed. Thanks again :)

Comment: Code 4 is Javascript. Not CSS. You need to add it to the location of your template where you can add custom Javascript. First do that then let me know what happens. Don't offer to give your site access to anybody!

Comment: So I've been searching up Google on how to 'add it to the location of your template where you can add custom Javascript' and come up empty. Where am I supposed to put code 4?  Am I supposed to install a plugin for adding custom Javascript?

Comment: See my update. You may have to make the changes directly in your HTML file.

Comment: Great news, I followed your advice and now the 'tags' and 'choose featured' options are gone. But as a problem is solved, another arises... The final 'submit' post button has disappeared mysteriously. The code in my submission form.php is here https://codeshare.io/NUSLy Apart from that I still have no idea what you mean by 'If you don't have a way to customize your Javascript easily, then add a <script></script> block directly in your HTML in your form file.' I need more explanation on that part. Thanks for your time, I really do appreciate it.

Comment: I find that by removing '<div id="fep-tags" style="display:none !important;">' on the 45th line puts back the submit button, but brings back the 'tag' option.